# CSS filter blur not blurring edges

Tags: css, css-filters

When I apply the blur filter to my markup the edges are not being blurred. I would like the entire region to be blurred.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="image">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
}

.inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: url(/images/400x300.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: fill;
}

.image:before {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0px;
  content: "text";
  position: absolute;
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  background: url(/images/400x300.jpg)  no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: fill;
  -webkit-filter: blur(12px);
  filter: blur(12px);
}
```

Codepen:

http://codepen.io/aaronbalthaser/pen/qNOYdE

The Codepen shows the blurred region. It is kind of like a footer but as you can see the edges are not blurred. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `overflow: hidden` and stretch a little bit the blurred image. I have set `width` to `110%`, height to `35%`, `left`, `right` and `bottom` to `-5%` (the added percentage to `width` and `height`). Hope this is what you want.

```css
html,
body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
}

.inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: url(http://attic24.typepad.com/.a/6a00e551101c548834017d3d4fde82970c-500wi) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: fill;
}

.image:before {
  left: -5%;
  right: -5%;
  bottom: -5%;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 35%;
  width: 110%;
  background: url(http://attic24.typepad.com/.a/6a00e551101c548834017d3d4fde82970c-500wi)  no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: fill;
  -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
  filter: blur(8px);
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
   <div class="inner">
     <div class="image">

     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```